# Reciprocal circles on complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

The expression $z + \exp(j\varphi)$ is a circle of unit radius on the complex plane, displaced by the complex vector $z$. The reciprocal of this expression $1/(\exp(j\varphi)+z)$ , I know, is also a circle (although there are limiting cases of straight lines) but I am having difficulty proving this.

Comment: Your posts will be easier to read if you use $\LaTeX$ markup; see [here for an introduction to posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  A starting point for your investigation is to determine the relationship between $z^{-1}$ and the center of the "reciprocal circle".

Comment: Try letting $z=x+iy$ and $\exp(i\phi) = \cos\phi+i\sin\phi$. Then compute the reciprocal, grouping the real and imaginary terms together.

Comment: @Troy : Your proposal yield this: $$\frac 1 {z+\exp(j\varphi)} = \frac{\bar z + \exp(-j\varphi)}{\Big(z + \exp(j\varphi)\Big) \Big(\bar z + \exp(-j\varphi) \Big)}$$ $$= \frac{\bar z + \exp(-j\varphi)}{|z|^2 + \exp(j\varphi) + \exp(-j\varphi) + 1} = \frac{\bar z + \exp(-j\varphi)}{|z|^2 + 2\cos(\varphi) + 1}$$  Did you have in mind something to do after that? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy in fact I'm stuck at the same point... for that expression to be a circle the denominator shoud not depend on $\phi$ ... or am I missing something? I'm trying to solve the same exercise in this way and rather than creating a new question I am trying to revamp this one. thanks

Comment: @MichaelHardy  actually I believe your expression is $$ \frac{\bar{z}+exp(-j\phi)}{{\vert{z}\vert}^2+2Rcos(\phi)+2Isin(\phi)+1}$$ where $R$ and $I$ are the real part and the imaginary part of $z$. At least this works for $z=0$. But from this point I don't know how to move on.

Comment: @l4teLearner : Before dealing wiht the substance of your comment, could I suggest better typesetting, thus: $$ \frac{\bar{z}+\exp(-j\phi)}{{\vert{z}\vert}^2+2R\cos(\phi)+2I\sin(\phi)+1} $$ The backslash in `\exp` and `\cos` and `\sin` does not only prevent italicization but also results in context-dependent spacing, so that, for example, the space to the right of $\sin$ in $\sin\varphi$ differs from that in $\sin(\varphi). \qquad$

Comment: @l4teLearner : I see: The denominator should have been
$$
|z|^2 + (z+\overline z)\cos\varphi +j(-z+\overline z) \sin\varphi + 1,
$$
and $z+\overline z$ and $j(-z+\overline z)$ are both real.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you! but even in this last version, the denominator seems to depend on $\varphi$. how can I further trasform the full expression to show that indeed the curve it represents is a circle (if $z$ stays constant and $\varphi$ varies)?

Comment: @l4teLearner : True ... I wasn't attempting a proof, but merely writing a comment.